# How do I install driver for the Linksys WUSB6300?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, adapter

I recently installed Ubuntu´s recent os 14.04 and am unable to install the driver for my wireless adapter which is the Linksys WUSB6300. Is there any way to configure the driver in any way, or should I purchase another one?

Comment: "unable to install the driver" ... What have you tried? Any errors? Did you try this http://science.opposingviews.com/ubuntu-work-linksys-wireless-card-11543.html ?

Comment: I think that it only applies for the earlier versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Please install a new driver:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
make
```

Reinstallation after a kernel upgrade:

```
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Directions come from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2200496).

Comment: 04:33 AM Sun Nov 15# modprobe -v 8812au
FATAL: Module 8812au not found.