# 16.04 Linksys WUSB6300 Install Driver

Tags: drivers, wireless

I am trying to install this wifi dongle that I just bought to replace another dongle that I couldn't configure just to find that I couldn't configure this dongle either. Most of the answers related to this point to [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2200496&s=8c959defc54344ac508faa6a5c4be766&p=12905494#post12905494). I followed those directions but that "didn't work" so I rolled them back by running `sudo make uninstall` in the `rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux` directory. Then I also tried going to the "additional drivers" gui and selecting the driver from there. This yielded the same result.

The line from my `lsusb` that I am looking to get to run my wifi

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 13b1:003f Linksys WUSB6300 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8812AU]
```

My current `iwconfig` output

```
enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I found this other SO question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520870/how-do-i-install-driver-for-the-linksys-wusb6300) and had the same message as @Herman Jaramillo noted in the comment `Module 8812au not found`

Here is a screenshot of my "Additional Drivers" gui. [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deo4T.png)

Edit

This is the [pastebin link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17209968/) with the output of the script linked in the comment below. The one I am interested in getting to work is the Linksys device listed on line 41.

Edit

The SO software encouraged me to edit my question to explain why it is not a duplicate of the answer pointed to. It is not a duplicate because this question is not about the Edimax wifi dongle but a different dongle the Linksys dongle present in the output of `lsusb`.

**I am editing this question again to explain how it is not a duplicate of the linked answer** The linked answer is related to the EDIMAX dongle *that is installed on this system* but *is not what this question is about* the question clearly reads in the title that it is about the Linksys WUSB3600. Please kindly do not disregard my attempt to mark this as a non duplicate.

Final Edit, my solution

Because this question was improperly marked as a duplicate I cannot answer it in the proper stackexchange way. I will add my answer here for anyone that finds it useful. The problem that I was having the entire time was related to the secure boot and UEFI features that I have never used before. When you disable secure boot when installing drivers, the system asks you for a password. On your next restart, there will be a blue screen that comes up with something about MOK Managemnt. THIS IS WHERE YOU USE THAT PASSWORD THAT YOU PUT IN EARLIER. You SHOULD press a key to enter MOK management, then you will provide details of the password that you entered earlier. Only then will the driver upgrades be applied. Hopefully this question will be made a non-duplicate so that the answer can be made in the usual way. I worked on this for several hours before finding out that MOK had "Shim UEFI Key Management" had anything to do with disabling secure boot. These UIs should be changed to reflect that fact.

Comment: Download [this script](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/522934) and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/785708/edit) your question to include a link to the pastebin output. This way people can have an overview.

Comment: I am not trying to get the EDIMAX adapter working, it (sortof) works now. I got a new Linksys adapter and that is the one that I cannot seem to get configured.

Comment: The driver *8812au* is correct for your 13b1:003f device. The Edimax mentioned in the possibly duplicate answer and the Linksys you have use the same chipset.

Comment: I am glad that it is the correct driver, I am still a bit confused as to why it does not show up in `iwconfig`

Comment: I edited this question again to indicate how it is not in fact a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: It is a duplicate. You could suggest an adit, or write another answer for the duplicate answer. The related answer is: http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-dkms-modules-in-ubuntu-16/762255?s=5|0.7008#762255 The problem is not because of another brand.

Comment: I would completely agree with you @Pilot6 the answer that you linked to does solve my question. I still do not believe my question to be a duplicate of that question but the solution was the same. Either way, the question that my question is currently marked as a duplicate of is not a duplicate of my question as you can see.

Comment: There are very many wireless brands. But for linux systems brands do not matter. Only the chip is important. It is not bad that the answer has been marked as a duplicate. It will help people to find the correct solution. It does not make any sense to keep separate questions regarding same hardware IMO. But your question may still be re-opened. It has 3 votes already.

Comment: My point is that the question that this question is marked as a duplicate of *does not contain the solution that worked for me* the one that you linked to should work although I'm not sure because I didn't try it.